# ¿Google permite duplicar y subir la misma aplicación en idiomas distintos?

Tags: android

tengo una duda.

Google permite subir una app con el mismo contenido pero en otro idioma?, es decir, clonaria mi misma app y la subiría en otro idioma.

Se que es poco practico y lo mejor es agregar el idioma a la misma app. Pero solo es una duda.

Comment: Yo creo que seria algo como esto lo que ocupas, https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844778?hl=en

Comment: En el caso que expones tendrías que crear paquetes distintos y subirlos de forma individual a Play Store, por lo que estaríamos hablando de una App por cada idioma.  Sí puedes ofrecer la misma App en varios idiomas, [como explica la documentación de Android](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages). Tampoco es tan complicado y las ventajas son enormes. Si un usuario quiere cambiar de idioma no tendría que borrar la App actual, buscar la App del nuevo idioma para instalarla, etc. Aparte de que tendrías todo centralizado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes subir a Google Play la misma aplicaciòn con otro idioma, no hay ningùn problema.

Pero en realidad **no es una buena pràctica**, por dos razones:

1. Lo ideal es implementar compatibilidad para diferentes idiomas en tu aplicaciòn, por ejemplo:

Strings en inglés (configuración local predeterminada), definir textos en: `/values/strings.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello World!</string>
</resources>
```

Strings en español (configuración regional de es), definir textos en: `/values-es/strings.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <string name="hello_world">¡Hola Mundo!</string>
</resources>
```

Revisa:

**[Cómo brindar compatibilidad con diferentes idiomas y culturas](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages?hl=es-419)**

2 Ademàs, si deseas subir otra aplicaciòn a Google Play, tendrìas que definir un id de aplicaciòn por cada versiòn de tu aplicacion con idioma diferente.

Ejemplo:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mariangel.myapp_espanol"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    ...
}
```

otra version de tu app serìa:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mariangel.myapp_ingles"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    ...
}
```

Revisa:

**[Cómo establecer el ID de aplicación](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id)**